# Really need to understand CENTOS fdisk -l output

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I am running centos on a server and the HDD config for my server is 2 1 tb drives with 32 gb RAM. Now when I use fdisk -l command, i see the below output which is really not understandable. Could anyone please help me here? Also why does LINUX LVM exists on both the disks

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b3ea7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953523711   976760832   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00052e26

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048  1953523711   976248832   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 968 MB, 968884224 bytes, 1892352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x909ce9e0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             145     1892351      946103+   6  FAT16

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Linux Logical volume manager (LVM).  This is a layer between your physical disks and your filesystems that introduces the concepts of 'physical volumes' (PV), 'volume groups' (VG), and 'logical volumes' (LV).

In your setup, `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sda2`, the partitions of type "Linux LVM" are both physical volumes.  On top of these PV you will have one or more volume groups, which you can display with the command `vgdisplay` and within these volume groups you will have your logical volumes, which are what you were expecting to see in that fdisk output.  You can list your LVs with `lvdisplay`

You will also note the partition names given in `mount` output will reflect the LVM layout and give names in the form `/dev/mapper/VG-LV`.  The LVM layer may seem like a pointless middleman, but it allows you to allocate space to your logical volumes (and thus your filesystems) independently of your disk sizes.  In the future if you wanted to make `/home` bigger (or any LV you happen to have) you can add a new disk, make it a PV, add the PV to your VG and then grow your LV from the added space to increase your filesystem size.  This gives you much flexibility in managing your disk allocations.

You can see one of your logical volumes in the last part of your `fdisk` output:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
```

This infers you have a volume group named `centos` and this logical volume is named `root`.  You can get information about the centos VG with the command `vgdisplay centos`, which will reflect the total PV size allocated to it (likely close to 2 TB) and how much free space is in the VG (to create new LV or grow existing LV).  You can get information about the LV with `lvdisplay centos/root`, which will list information, including the size of the LV.  You can reference this LV like you would a normal partition, except instead of `/dev/sdaX` you will use `/dev/mapper/centos-root`.